# Returning an array in c for calculating number

Tags: c

As I am a beginner with c programming. I was trying to return an array in my program but it's not working properly.
Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    printf("Enter any three numbers separated with a single space : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    int * result = calc(x,y,z);
    printf("The big number is %d \n The middle number is %d \n The small number is %d", result[0], result[1], result[2]);
}
calc(int x, int y, int z){
    static int * result[3] = {0,0,0};
    if(x>y && x>z){
        result[0] = x;
        if(y<z){
            result[2] = y;
            result[1] = z;
        }
    }else if(y>x && y>z){
        result[0] = y;
        if(x<z){
            result[2] = x;
            result[1] = z;
        }
    }else if(z>x && z>y){
        result[0] = z;
        if(y<x){
            result[2] = y;
            result[1] = x;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've searched a lot but either i don't understand or the code isn't working for me.

Comment: You will not be able to use an array local as a result, because when you exit the routine, that storage is deallocated.   Start googling how to use `malloc`

Comment: @infixed it won't be deallocated if marked as `static`

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and treat them as errors.

Comment: @leo, true, I missed the `static`.   But I do notice now that calc does not have a return type of `int*`, which I suspect is a problem.  While the compiler didn't complain I can't guess.   Defining it after `main()` isn't going to help much either.

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  There are two valid signatures for the `main` function both of those signatures have a return type of `int`.  `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  and `int main( void )`  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the calc function -

```
int *result[3] = {0,0,0};
```

is an array of 3 pointers to integers.

An array of integers should just be declared as

```
int result[3] = {0,0,0};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *calc(int x, int y, int z);
int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    printf("Enter any three numbers separated with a single space : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    int * result = calc(x,y,z);
    printf("The big number is %d \n The middle number is %d \n The small number is %d", result[0], result[1], result[2]);
}
int *calc(int x, int y, int z){ // first this the right way to declare it
     static  int result[3] = {0,0,0};

    if(x>y && x>z){
        result[0] = x;
        if(y<z){
            result[2] = y;
            result[1] = z;
        } // second you forgot to consider the else case like this :) i 've changed it on the other ifs too
        else{
             result[1] = y;
            result[2] = z;
        }
    }
     if(y>x && y>z){
        result[0] = y;
        if(x<z){
            result[2] = x;
            result[1] = z;
        }else{
         result[1] = x;
            result[2] = z;
        }

    }
     if(z>x && z>y){
        result[0] = z;
        if(y<x){
            result[2] = y;
            result[1] = x;
        }else{
        result[1] = y;
            result[2] = x;}
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For various reasons, you cannot *return* an array from a function.  Usually the better option is to pass the target array as an argument to the function (assuming you know what the size of the array needs to be ahead of time):

```
/**
 * This version of calc doesn't return anything, so it's typed void
 */
void calc( int x, int y, int z, int *result, size_t result_size )
{
  if ( x > y && x > z )
    result[0] = x;
  ...
}

/**
 * Unless your compiler documentation *explicitly* lists void main()
 * as a valid signature, use int main( void ) instead.  
 */
int main( void )
{
  int result[3] = {0, 0, 0};
  ...
  calc( x, y, z, result, sizeof result / sizeof result[0] );
  ...
}
```

Unless your function is messing with a 0-terminated string (or some other sentinel value in the array contents), you need to pass the array size as a separate parameter.  Array expressions lose their "array-ness" when passed as a function argument, so you need to track their size separately (the `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]` won't work on a pointer).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your program.

1. `int * result = calc(x,y,z);` - but `calc` returns an `int` (as the return type is not specified)
2. `static int * result[3] = {0,0,0};` - `result` is an array of size `3` of pointers to int. But, you have initialized them as `0` each. This is not a problem exactly if you understand what is happening here. In fact, just a plain array would have been just fine.
3. `return result;` you are returning `result` but the return type of the function `calc` is int by default.
4. There is no prototype for the `calc` function.

This is what your program should look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int * calc(int, int, int);

void main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    printf("Enter any three numbers separated with a single space : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    int * result = calc(x,y,z);
    printf("The big number is %d \n The middle number is %d \n The small number is %d", result[0], result[1], result[2]);
}
int *calc(int x, int y, int z){
    static int result[3] = {0,0,0};
    if(x>y && x>z){
        result[0] = x;
        if(y<z){
            result[2] = y;
            result[1] = z;
        }
    }else if(y>x && y>z){
        result[0] = y;
        if(x<z){
            result[2] = x;
            result[1] = z;
        }
    }else if(z>x && z>y){
        result[0] = z;
        if(y<x){
            result[2] = y;
            result[1] = x;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Having said that, your program does not seem to work as you intend it to. Have a look at the outputs below:

```
Enter any three numbers separated with a single space : 12 33 4
The big number is 33 
 The middle number is 0 
 The small number is 0
shell returned 69


Enter any three numbers separated with a single space : 100 3 4
The big number is 100 
 The middle number is 4 
 The small number is 3
shell returned 70
```

You might want to work on the logic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use static, unless you know the implications. Considering you are a beginner, try to stick to local variables only
2. What you are trying to do is to return an array of 3 integers after it's been processed by the `calc` function. Here you have 2 choices:

   - Pass the "empty" `( {0,0,0} )` array as a parameter for the function and so `result` will be modified in the `main` scope too.
   - Return an array that has been initialized in `calc` function.

Either way you have to learn how C manages dynamically allocated memory.

1) You declare a pointer to the data type you desire

```
int *result;
```

2) You allocate memory for that pointer (basically beginner-ish speaking, it becomes an array)

```
result = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

You can either use `void* malloc(size_t memory_block)` (which doesn't initialize memory) or `void* calloc(size_t number_of_blocks, size_t block_size)` which sets all memory on 0

3) You process your data in `calc` function using `result` array.

4) Either way you choose do it (regarding 2.), your function should return something.
If you pass the array as a parameter it should return `void` else it should return `int*`, which basically translates as *it returns an pointer to an int* (and regarding that you allocated memory for that pointer, now it basically returns an array)